# JavaScript I have to click twice to select to element

Tags: javascript

Please anyone can help to fix the issue with my code, sometimes I have to click twice to select the next elements

```
var varientbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('clickthisbtn');

    for(let i = 0; i < varientbtn.length; i++) {
        varientbtn[i].onclick = function () {
          
            const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice"]');
            let selectedValue;
            let varientSelectedPrice;
          
            for (const rb of rbs) {
              if (rb.checked) {
                selectedValue = rb.value;
                varientSelectedPrice = rb.getAttribute("data-price");
                break;
              }
            }
            document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = selectedValue;
            document.getElementById('varientprice').innerHTML = varientSelectedPrice;
            console.log(selectedValue, varientSelectedPrice);
        }
    }
```

Live preview:
https://codepen.io/Elkazi/pen/wvJeErg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when one of labels be clicked, the checked value of related radio still not change.

Try this

```
 const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice"]');

    for(let i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
        rbs[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
            let selectedValue;
            let varientSelectedPrice;
          
            for (const rb of rbs) {
              if (rb.checked) {
                selectedValue = rb.value;
                varientSelectedPrice = rb.getAttribute("data-price");
                break;
              }
            }
            document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = selectedValue;
            document.getElementById('varientprice').innerHTML = varientSelectedPrice;
            console.log(selectedValue, varientSelectedPrice);
        });
    }

    rbs[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding event listener to the label element, you should make use of its **for** attribute to get the related input field. That way you don't have to run a loop for all inputs and will always get the latest/correct value.

this will point to the element on which the event handler is called.

```
var varientbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('clickthisbtn');

    for(let i = 0; i < varientbtn.length; i++) {
        varientbtn[i].onclick = function () {
         let relatedInput = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("for"));
            let selectedValue = relatedInput.value;
            let varientSelectedPrice = relatedInput.getAttribute("data-price");;
            document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = selectedValue;
            document.getElementById('varientprice').innerHTML = varientSelectedPrice;
            console.log(selectedValue, varientSelectedPrice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get it, I just start learning JS, my skills are not so good, I checked it's working perfectly now, Thank you 